# Move google map center point onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have initialized the Google Maps `load` function, and it works fine. There are also multiple markers with clusters. I haven't put markers and cluster codes here. Those are standard code. My code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    initialize();
});

function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(59.875405, 10.842099);
    var zoom = 10;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: zoom,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
}
function mapAnimate(){
    var map = google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"));
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(58.9633, 5.7189));
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

Then I want to move the map to another center position without re-generating the map. There is a link which calls the function `mapAnimate()`.

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="mapAnimate()">test</a>
```

But it does not work. I get an error like this:

```
TypeError: c[Eb] is not a function......
```

Actually I don't get the map instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your `map` variable outside the functions. That should do the trick.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    initialize();
});

var map;

function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(59.875405, 10.842099);
    var zoom = 10;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: zoom,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
}
function mapAnimate(){

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(58.9633, 5.7189));
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

But if you call the `mapAnimate()` function from a click event, I don't see why you would need that listener on the map object.

Comment: I actually figured it out myself by the time u answered. But thanks a lot anyway.